# WPF StringFormat to allow only positive numbers

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm, string-formatting

I only want to allow positive numbers as user input in my TextBox.

If I input `-10` and use

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Width, StringFormat={}{0:0.00;0.00}}" />
```

then it always displays positive numbers, but the Data behind is still negative.

How to do it right?

Comment: You won't do it with `StringFormat`. Do you handle setter of the `Width` property? If not you'll need to handle something like `PreviewTextInput` event on `TextBox`

Comment: I can do it with `Interaction.Behaviors` but I would prefer it in plain `StringFormat`

Comment: `StringFormat` doesn't work like that. Most robust solution would include `Math.Abs(value)` in the setter of the property and then raise `PropertyChanged` event. But if you cannot do that use your `Interaction.Behaviors` solution

Answer (score 3):

Since the validation rule enforces the value to be positive, I suggest to also check the value in the VM property to enforce/convert it as well:

```
private string _width;

public string Width
{
   get { return _width; }
   set 
       {
          int result;
          int.TryParse(value, out result);
          _width = (result < 0 ? result *-1 : result).ToString();   
          PropertyChanged("Width");
       } 
}
```

Comment: I am completely new to this, and the following question may be more than stupid. But could you please shortly explain how the setter in your code works? In every example I have seen so far, the setter processes a variable named `value` which contains the new value of the property. Where does your setter get the new value from, and where does `width` come from (in `int.TryParse(...)`)? Obviously, that `width` contains the new value, but how does / did the new value get in there?

Comment: Good catch. Updated code sample.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for the fast reply. Upvoted ...

Comment: The other option is to put the logic of providing a valid string into a xaml Converter. Look up examples of that, it might be more relevant to yorur situation.

Comment: Thank you very much again! Yes, I've seen such converters. I am currently just reading as much documentation and examples as possible and just tried to understand your code :-) Hence the question ...

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to handle this, such as OmegaMan's.  But my solution for this would be to not use a textbox at all. Sadly WPF has never been blessed with a spinbox/updown control out of the box, but the [extended WPFToolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) does have one. So why waste your time on parsing and handling all the nasty cases? Let the control do the heavy lifting.

```
<extToolkit:IntegerUpDown Value="{Binding Width}" Minimum="0"/>
```

Done

Comment: Link no longer works